# A series expansion

Tags: series-expansion

It might be a silly question. Actually I'm facing a problem expanding $(1+\frac{2}{x})^{\frac{i}{2}}$ for small $x$. Mathematica can not expand it. But it can of course expand $(1+\frac{2}{x})^{\frac{1}{2}}$ for small $x$. Is it related to properties of the expression ( like convergence etc)  or I need to use mathematica a bit carefully?

Comment: Is `i` the imaginary unit in your expression?

Comment: You can try raising the result of expanding the square root to `I`...

Comment: @march yes. It's $\sqrt{-1}$

Comment: @J.M. Actually I tried that. But didn't get anything useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps this, from `J.M.`'s hint:

```
Series[(1 + 1/x)^(1/2), {x, 0, 3}]
Series[(Normal@%)^I // Expand, {x, 0, 3}]
Expand@Normal@%
```

[image]

Or, perhaps this: (per another of `J.M.`'s hints):

```
Series[(1 + 1/x)^(1/2), {x, 0, 3}]
Series[%, {x, 0, 3}]^I
Normal@Expand@%
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! It looks good. But probably I should check it by hand once..

Comment: Actually, `Series[(1 + 1/x)^(1/2), {x, 0, 3}]^I // Normal` is what I'd have done. ;)

Comment: @J.M. Well of course you'd have done something smarter than me. :)

Answer (score 1):

Is this acceptable where you introduce the factor "c"?

```
Series[(1 + 2/x)^(I/3), {x, c, 4}]

(* (1 + 2/c)^(I/3) - (2 I (1 + 2/c)^(-1 + I/3) (x - c))/(3 c^2) + (
 2 I (1 + 2/c)^(I/3) ((3 + I) + 3 c) (x - c)^2)/(9 c^2 (2 + c)^2) - (
 2 I (1 + 2/c)^(I/
  3) ((34 + 18 I) + (54 + 18 I) c + 27 c^2) (x - c)^3)/(
 81 c^3 (2 + c)^3) + ....*)  

Limit[%, x -> 0]

(* (((2 + c)/
  c)^(I/3) ((3260 + 
     2640 I) + (6912 + 4704 I) c + (5508 + 2916 I) c^2 + (1944 + 
      648 I) c^3 + 243 c^4))/(243 (2 + c)^4) *)
```

Comment: Then I need to replace c by x?

Comment: @pinu  The meaning of "c" here is the point at which you expand the series on "x". So you reach singularity if you put "c=0", maybe try a small number for c.